# Payment provider web hook experiencing a 403 forbidden status

Tags: nginx, php, http-status-code-403

Our payment provider has been having issues hitting our webhook after a transaction. The server responds with a 403 status.

NGINX shows the request is retried twice but fails. Interestingly if I copy the request and send it myself via postman there's no issue.

Where can I look to try and diagnose this? The server is running NGINX/PHP7.

Comment: Check your error logs.

Comment: Is there anywhere other than the usual log file. Thats just showing the request being made and followed by a 403 and the payload.

Comment: It's whatever log you configured in nginx. If nothing is there, then check your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable a php error log by setting something like the following in the **php.ini** configuration file:

```
error_log = /tmp/php_error_log
```

To find where your **php.ini** file is stored you can use the `php -i` command:

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

After you update **php.ini** you will need to restart any existing processes to pick up the configuration change, specifically in your case **nginx** will need to be restarted.